# MKPolylineView initWithPolyLine: is deprecated in iOS 7

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit, deprecated, mkpolyline

I am getting the following error: `initWithPolyline`: is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 7.0

```
MKPolylineView *lineView = [[MKPolylineView alloc] 
       initWithPolyline:overlay];
```

What is the replacement  method of instead of this ?

Comment: Use MKPolylineRenderer as the answer says but you also need to implement the rendererForOverlay delegate method instead of viewForOverlay.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKPolylineView_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/MKPolylineView/initWithPolyline:) for `initWithPolyline:`. Read the Deprecation Statement which says to use an `MKPolylineRenderer` object instead.

Answer (score 11):

You should use `(MKOverlayRenderer *)` type delegate instead of `(MKOverlayView *)` type delegate. And return `MKPolylineRenderer` instead of `MKPolylineView`.

```
-(MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView
           rendererForOverlay:(id<MKOverlay>)overlay {

   MKPolylineRenderer *renderer = [[MKPolylineRenderer alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay];
   renderer.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor];
   renderer.lineWidth = 5.0;

   return renderer;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You will like to take a look to [MKPolylineRenderer](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKPolylineRenderer_class/index.html), specifically to -initWithPolyline (avalilable in iOS 7 and later).